# Choosing binomial distribution instead of hypergeometric without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The problem is: A batch of $10$ rocket cover gaskets contains 4 defective gaskets. If we draw samples of size $3$ without replacement, from the batch of $10$, find the probability that a sample contains $2$ defective gaskets.

Since this problem doesn't have replacement, I know to use hypergeometric distribution because the probability isn't the same each trial. However, I was wondering if it was possible to use binomial distribution for this problem, and problems without replacement period.

Comment: But binomial distribution assumes probability of a success (picking a defective) is constant on each of the 3 draws. Thus we wouldn't have the same situation anymore

Comment: why you want to use binomial distribution?

Comment: Why don't you try it both ways and compare the answers?